# SPARQL queries from Android device

Tags: android, sparql

Is there an implementation for android that can act like a client to run SPARQL queries?

I couldn't find anything here http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlImplementations but maybe someone knows something more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://monead.com/blog/?p=1420 describes some interesting Android software for doing local queries. If you want the Android device to be a client querying a remote SPARQL endpoint, why not just used a web form? I wrote about how easy it is to format SPARQL XML results for a mobile phone at http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2011/10/displaying-sparql-results-on-a.html, if that's any help.